# When to use the adverb "there"

Tags: adverbs

> I wonder if *there* is still someone around here.

If *there* means that you are indicating something in the distance, why it is necessary to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In English, we use the word "there" in two different ways: as an adverb and as an [expletive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_expletive).

The italicized *there* in your first sentence is an expletive. As an expletive, *there* does not indicate a location as it does when used as an adverb. Think of the expletive *there* as meaning the existence or presence of something. Also note that it typically occurs with some form of *be*: There is/are..., There was/were, etc.

> (expletive *there* with "be" verb) **There is** a problem with this computer. *A problem exists with this computer.*
>
> (adverbial "locational" *there*) I went to Tokyo last month. I saw many people **there**. *I saw many people in that place.*

For some additional explanation and examples, check [here](http://www.ling.upenn.edu/%7Ebeatrice/syntax-textbook/box-expletives.html).

Comment: I'd put `there is` bold instead of just `there`: the `there is` is the expression that means the existence or presence of something.

Comment: Good point, since it partners up with the "be" copula. I'll make the edit.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, "there" is not something at a distance (I think you are thinking of "asoko" in Japanese), rather it refers to something that exists.

There is explanation and examples of this usage here: http://www.grammar.cl/Present/ThereIsThereAre.htm

(^^^^ see how I used it up there?)